# Look for popups while opening a document

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, async-await

I am using C# to read Word Documents but when I open some. They have a popup that opens.

I want to detect and close these popups and close them so the program wont have to wait for the user.

I have the code that is shown below where i am trying to use Async so i can run the open word document code and the window count at the same time. i can figure out how to loop the window count code till the doc open code finishes.

```
Word.Application WordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
WordApp.Visible = false;

Task t1 = new Task(() =>
{
    Word.Document Doc = WordApp.Documents.OpenNoRepairDialog(FileName: path, ConfirmConversions: false, ReadOnly: true, AddToRecentFiles: false, NoEncodingDialog: true);
});
Task t2 = new Task(() =>
{
    Application.Current.MainWindow.Count
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to read the document, you don't need the Word application for that:

[How to: Open a word processing document for read-only access (Open XML SDK)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-open-a-word-processing-document-for-read-only-access)